# How to Fix 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a function Frequency. it takes input a list and returns the element which is occurred maximum and min number of times

```
def frequency(l):
    l.sort()
    cont=[]
    for i in l:
        cont.append(l.count(i))
    l=min(cont)
    h=max(cont)
    maxelements=[]
    minelements=[]
    for j in range(len(cont)):
        if cont[j]==l:
            minelements.append(l[j])
        elif cont[j]==h:
            maxelements.append(l[j])
    return(maxelements,minelements)

frequency([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12])
([7], [13])
```

Comment: The error traceback would be helpful, though there are several easier and faster ways to do this problem such as using a `Counter` object or just using a dictionary to keep track of the count. What you have is O(n^2) when it could be O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is happening because you're trying to do `l[j]`. `l` is an `int`, as you initialized it here `l=min(cont)`. You're treating it as if it were a `list`, where you could grab elements from it.

Learn more about `min()` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min

> min(iterable, *[, key, default])
>
> min(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
>
> Return the smallest item in an iterable or the smallest of two or more arguments.
>
> If one positional argument is provided, it should be an iterable. The smallest item in the iterable is returned. If two or more positional arguments are provided, the smallest of the positional arguments is returned.